# Spring Security Deletes Custom Request Parameters from my /login URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've seen some threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933188/how-to-pass-parameter-along-with-logout-success-url-in-spring-security) but they're old and I'm loathe to add any big implementations of various filters and loaders.

I'm handling a `/logout` manually as follows, then redirect to my `/login` (Login is managed by Spring Security) with a custom param:

```
@GetMapping("/participant/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("exitMsg") String exitMsg){
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        securityContextLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
        return "redirect:/participant/login?logout=true&exitMsg=" + exitMsg;
    }

@GetMapping("/participant/login")
    public ModelAndView  loginPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            @RequestParam("exitMsg") String exitMsg) {
            // exitMsg is NULL here!
    }
```

In the debugger I see the correct formation of the URL and then I hit `/login` correctly, **but the request parameter to /login (exitMsg) is lost**.

So how can I keep custom params to `/login` ?

Spring Security Config:

```
        http.antMatcher("/participant/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/participant/id/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/participant/faq").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/participant/forgetPassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/participant/securityQuestions").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/participant/securityCheck").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/participant/resetPassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/participant/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/participant/login").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/participant/login?error").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/participant/home")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .logout()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this fast solution -- use the **SavedRequest** object which holds Req Params to /login,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30205815/1005607